# にあった instead of であった

Tags: particle-に

> 反応速度論の目的は反応速度を解析することで、反応機構や化学反応の物理学的本質を解明することにあった。

The above sentence is from the Wikipedia article [反応速度論](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%8D%E5%BF%9C%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E8%AB%96). I don't understand the use of the particle に at the end. In scientific writing, I expected であった or in this case である, since this field of study still exists and is not in the past.

Could this be a typo, or is it a real grammatical construction. If the latter, how is this structure typically used?

Comment: "I expected ... である, since this field of study still exists and is not in the past." -> 過去形になっている理由は、その次の２文を読めば分かります。「[今日]{こんにち}においては...」とか「今日の反応速度論は...」のところ。

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a typo.

That に is a location particle and the あった is the past-tense form of ある, the inanimate existential verb. So an English equivalent would be:

> The object (...) **consisted in** (...).

On the other hand, である is a copula, thus the English version would have been:

> The object (...) **was** (...).

As to why it's にあった, not にある, that's because the sentence does seem to talk about what the object of 反応速度論 was -- no, I mean *consisted in*, in the past.